# Will back EMF be a problem when operating a solder fume extractor with a foot switch?

Tags: ac, switches

I have an Xytronic HV-2 solder fume extractor. Operating it is cumbersome since I have to crawl under my desk to switch it on and off each time. I'd like to add a foot switch for easy operation. I thought of simply adding the switch in line. Since those things got a substantial electric motor I am wondering if I would have to worry about back EMF at the switch.

Answer (score 1):

The foot switch should have a separate inductive load or motor rating to account for this. If the one you are looking at does not, either use a different switch or a relay.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Somehow it didn't occur to me that I might not be the only one having this problem. I'll have a look in the datasheets!

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of foot switches used with that kind of load. However, general industrial distributors (looking at you McMaster) may not know enough to rate them properly and you may have to call them or dig a bit (since some of them also obscure the manufacturer and don't make manuals available online).

For example, here is one from [Grainger](https://www.grainger.ca/en/product/p/WWG2W810?gucid=N:N:PS:Paid:GGL:CSM-9224:FDKJTB:20501128:APZ_1):

[image]

The key rating here being the 1/2HP, so it will support up to a 373W motor. Unless your extractor is more like a wind tunnel that is probably adequate.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed reply! Just checked the label on my fume extractor and power draw is stated with 240w so 0.5hp should be good enough.  I'll have a look around at whats on offer. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.